# How do you change word break characters in OS X 10.11 El Capitan (or Xcode 7.2)?

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan

When I double-click text in an Xcode string to select an entire word, any text connected to it with a dot (.) will also get selected. I would like to make that not happen so that dots and other characters behave as word break character, like dashes (-). Is there a way to change this either in general for OS X 10.11 or just specifically for Xcode 7.2?

I notice this happens in XCode and in TextEdit so I'm guessing it would be an OS X setting, but then it doesn't happen when double-clicking on Xcode variables so I'm not sure.